# Object and function confusion - different output

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and I am comparing with `function User() { }` and `var User2 = { }`

```
function User() {

    this.name =  '';

    this.love = function love(user) {
        console.log(this.name + " Love " + user.name);
    }
}

bill = new User();
sarah = new User();

bill.name = "Bill";
sarah.name = "Sarah";
```

Output:

```
bill.love(sarah); //Bill Love Sarah
```

When I replace function User() to var object, for example:

```
var User2 = {

    name: "",

    love: function love(user) {
        console.log(this.name + " Love " + user.name);
    }
}

bill =  User2;
sarah = User2;

bill.name = "Bill";
sarah.name = "Sarah";
```

Output:

```
bill.love(sarah); //Sarah Love Sarah
```

Why both output is different?

Comment: In the second case, you only have one object, and both `bill` and `sarah` point to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The names are the same because of this:

```
bill =  User2;
sarah = User2;
```

`bill` and `sarah` both point to the *same* object. They are *identical* to each other.

You can check this in JavaScript:

```
bill == sarah; // true
bill === sarah; // true
```

In JavaScript comparing two objects with `==` or `===` means [comparing their references](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). Because they are defined to be the same object `User2`, they have the *reference* to the *same* object, hence they are equal and all changes are made to the same object.

In your second example, `sarah` and `bill` are *assigned* the same object, wereas in your first example `sarah` and `bill` are assigned *instances* of a function. The instances are not identical, the object with itself is.

---

```
bill.name = "Bill";
```

is the same as

```
sarah.name = "Bill";
```

and

```
sarah.name = "Sarah";
```

is the same as

```
bill.name = "Sarah";
```

---

Your solution with the function constructors is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 3):

You are using references, not inheritance. In order to inherit, use Object [create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) method:

```
bill =  Object.create(User2);
sarah = Object.create(User2);
```

> The Object.create() method creates a new object with the specified prototype object and properties.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you are making 2 different instances of User (thanks to the `new` keyword). So, each of them has a different name value.

In the second example, you store the instance of a literal object (`var literalObj = {}` notation) in the User2 variable. So, when doing `bill = User2`, you are storing the reference to the instance User2 in the bill variable. Then, you store the User2 instance reference to the sarah variable. At this point, User2, bill and sarah have the same reference to the object with the name property and the love method.

Finally, you set the name of that instance to "Bill", then to "Sarah", so "Bill" is replaced by "Sarah" because you are updating the **same** instance. At the end, `bill === sarah` so bill.name === sarah.name which is "Sarah".

Answer (score 1):

User is a function and User2 is a variable.

In this code  :

```
function User() {

        this.name =  '';

        this.love = function love(user) {
            console.log(this.name + " Love " + user.name);
        }
    }

    bill = new User();
    sarah = new User();

    bill.name = "Bill";
    sarah.name = "Sarah";
```

*bill* and *sarah* are two different object of **User** with different **values**.

But in this code  :

```
var User2 = {

    name: "",

    love: function love(user) {
        console.log(this.name + " Love " + user.name);
    }
}

bill =  User2;
sarah = User2;

bill.name = "Bill";
sarah.name = "Sarah";
```

Both *bill* and *sarah* are referring to the **same variable** .

Initially **User2.name was ""**

from this line :

```
 bill.name = "Bill";
```

User2.name got updated to **"Bill"**

and with this line

```
sarah.name = "Sarah";
```

User2.name got updated to **"Sarah"**

Thats why the second output is :

> Sarah Love Sarah

Comment: _“User is a function and User2 is a variable.”_ — that’s not the point. The point is that `sarah` and `bill` are _assigned_ the same object in the second example, whereas in the first example `sarah` and `bill` are assigned _instances_ of a function. The instances are not identical, the object with itself is.

Comment: Yeah !! Thanks for very nice explanation :)