# javascript: Strange behavior when setting null for value of one object

Tags: javascript

I've got 2 different objects: pos_cashinout and pos_cashinout_lokaal.

First I set pos_cashinout equal to pos_cashinout_lokaal.
Then I set one key of pos_cashinout_lokaal to null, but when I check the values they become null for both objects.

This is my code:

```js
pos_cashinout = pos_cashinout_lokaal;
window.alert(pos_cashinout.toSource());
window.alert(pos_cashinout_lokaal.toSource());
             
pos_cashinout_lokaal.verrichting = null;
             
window.alert(pos_cashinout.verrichting);
window.alert(pos_cashinout_lokaal.verrichting);
```

The output of the window alerts in the same sequence:

> ({aan:"Jos", bedraguit:10, kassier:"Robbe", opmerking:"Einde dag",
>   bedragin:10013, id:1, verrichting:"Your Company"})
>
> ({aan:"Jos", bedraguit:10, kassier:"Robbe", opmerking:"Einde dag",
>   bedragin:10013, id:1, verrichting:"Your Company"})
>
> null
>
> null

I thought, and intended that only pos_cashinout_lokaal.verrichting would be null?

**edit:** objects are indeed only referenced the way I did it.
Found the solution here: [How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

I got it working like this:

```
cloneobject: function(obj){
    if (null == obj || "object" != typeof obj) return obj;
    var copy = obj.constructor();
    for (var attr in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) copy[attr] = obj[attr];
    }
    return copy;
},

pos_cashinout = this.cloneobject(pos_cashinout_lokaal)
```

Comment: Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32166043/4642212). You’ve got the same object referenced by two variables. A change to one variable is a change to the same object.

Comment: Thanks Juhana, found my answer there.